# Format variable containing special characters for comparison using -like operator

Tags: powershell, comparison, powercli

I ran into a problem where some variables, that I'm comparing against using the like operator, contain square brackets and parenthesis.

I am using the VMware PowerCLI plugin (which should be irrelevant) and my expression is as follows -

```
Get-VM | Where { (Get-CDDrive $_).ISOPath -like "*$ISOLocation*" }
```

It is failing to identify the similarity between strings when the value of `$ISOLocation` is `[datastore1 (13)] iso/rhel6.4_kickstart.iso`. I believe this is due to the special characters. How can I escape these characters before the previously mentioned command, or how can I better achieve this comparison?

Comment: Why are you using `-like` if you know the entire path?

Comment: @carlpett Because the path can vary to be something else completely, like part of the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as bracket are concerned, you've got the Microsoft official answer in an old Technet Windows [PowerShell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx).

In you case try :

```
``[datastore1 (13)``] iso/rhel6.4_kickstart.iso
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be doable with the use of `-replace` on the variable.